# Excel 2010 - Copy doesn't drag / Pasting option is only Unicode Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, copy-paste

It seems that when I copy a cell, it is not highlighted and cannot be dragged and the only paste option is unicode text or text.

I checked `File`-`Options`-`Advanced-Editing` Options and I have my "`Enable fill handle and cell drag...`" as checked.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Any comments would be helpful

Comment: Without copying the cell, if you put the mouse on the outline of the active cell, does it change to the move pointer? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/display-or-hide-the-fill-handle-HP001216376.aspx

Comment: @Kojo: What does the cell contains?

Answer (score 1):

I face the similar issue with Excel 2003.
If you have installed Skype-Click-to-Call, just removed it to resolve this issue.